# package fat jar using gradle with transitive dependencies

Tags: gradle

I would like to create fat jar using gradle. I am using the shadowJar plugin(com.github.johnrengelman.shadow).

The problem that I am facing is that I cannot find a way to instruct the plugin to package a certain libraries with their transitive dependencies.

For example: I am using hive-jdbc which depends on org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2, however the final jar packaged by shadowJar does not include httpclient

Another option is to drop the shadowJar section from the gradle.build file, but then the plugin will include everything that is part of the compile classpath and huge jar file will be created.

I am using this build file in order to package a jar for spark-submmit that includes many libraries as part of the runtime environment, so I do not need all the compile dependencies to be packaged (just the ones I am specifying explicitly and their transitive dependencies)

build.gradle:

```
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.AppendingTransformer

plugins {
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "2.0.3"
}


apply from: "../Parent_2.2/build.gradle"
group 'com.ebates.bigdata'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

dependencies{
    compile("com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0"){force = true}
    compile("org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.6.5"){force = true}
    compile("org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.6.5"){force = true}
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1207"){force = true}
    compile("org.apache.hive:hive-jdbc:2.2.0"){force = true}
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}
shadowJar {

    mergeServiceFiles()
    transform(AppendingTransformer) {
        resource = 'reference.conf'
        shadowJar.classifier = ""
        zip64 true
        dependencies {
            include(dependency("com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0"))
            include(dependency("org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1207"))
            include(dependency("org.apache.hive:hive-jdbc:2.2.0"))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bad example: just use `hive-jdbc-standalone.jar`to get rid of 95% of these dependencies.

Comment: The plugin documentation (http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/#filtering_dependencies) shows several strategies: excluding rather than including, using regexes.